# I am trying to put some data into mysql via mysql-shell but it's not working

Tags: mysql

when I fire this query in MySQL-shell it throws an error. I don't have any idea why it is throwing an error.

```
INSERT INTO course_metadata_organization 
 (partner, key, name) VALUES ('1', 'test', 'Norway');
```

error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, name)
VALUES ('1', 'test', 'Norway')' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO course_metadata_organization 
 (`partner`, `key`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'test', 'Norway');
```

use ` for column names

Comment: why this backtick need?